# Setting unique characters in key's name with keylset

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to set a keyed list with `keylset`, but apparently it doesn't accept unique characters like a dot (`.`) in the key's name.
For example, the following code (Tcl 8.5):

```
puts "conditions=$conditions"
if {[llength $conditions] > 0} {
    foreach {name value} $conditions {
        puts "keylset data \"$name\" \"$value\""
        keylset data "$name" "$value"
    }
}
puts "keylkeys data = [keylkeys data]"
```

Outputs:

```
conditions=abc.de hello bar.world Stack bar.dog Exchange
keylset data "abc.de" "hello"
keylset data "bar.world" "Stack"
keylset data "bar.dog" "Exchange"
keylkeys data = abc bar
```

Notice that only 2 keys received from running `keylkeys data`.
Couldn't find any documentation for this. Perhaps I'm not using it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyed lists use `.` as a structured key separator; the part after the `.` is a sub-key. If we print the overall keyed list, we can see how things have been interpreted:

```
% puts $data
{abc {{de hello}}} {bar {{world Stack} {dog Exchange}}}
```

If you need arbitrary keys, use dictionaries (available from Tcl 8.5) instead.

```
dict set example abc.de "hello"
dict set example bar.world "Stack"
dict set example bar.dog "Exchange"
puts $example
#--> abc.de hello bar.world Stack bar.dog Exchange
puts [dict keys $example]
#--> abc.de bar.world bar.dog
```